# Chrome Extension Cross-Origin Requests in Background Script Blocked

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I try to fetch data from my background script like recommended [here](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches) but it always got blocked. did i miss something?

Background.js:

```
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['sigurl'], function(result) {
      console.log(result.sigurl);
      fetch(result.sigurl)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.text();
      })
      .then((html) => {
        console.log(html);
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'sig': html}, function() {});
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('Failed to fetch page: ', err);
        });
    });
```

Console:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://example.com/test.html' from origin 'chrome-extension://pbflkjmmkpgddamdcihlbggdccjmjmbk' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

use no-cors mode didn’t work either.

Comment: Add `http://example.com/` to [permissions in manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission).

Comment: @wOxxOm Isn't background script supposed not to be blocked by CORS?

Comment: @avalanche1, see the link I gave in my first comment.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you, the link really helps me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for my problem is adding

```
"permissions": [
    "https://*/"
  ]
```

to my manifest.json

Thank you to wOxxOm for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I wonder if this will produce `Extension can: Read and change all your data on the websites you visit` warning? @wOxxOm

Comment: i just realised you should only add the website you wanna access in the permssions to limit malicious code as shown in the link given by WOxxOm